# How to connect to WIFI in OpenBSD?

Tags: networking, wifi, openbsd

**Question**: How to connect to WIFI on OpenBSD?

---

Currently I have tried:

```
# ifconfig iwn0 nwid <network-name> wpa wpapsk `wpa-psk <network-name> <my-passphrase>`
```

But it responds with `ifconfig: SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted`

The only internet connection I have been able to utilize so far is via ethernet (also used during install).

---

Answer (score 8):

No. The above command should have given you "ksh: wpa-psk: not found" and "ifconfig: wpapsk: bad value". Where did you get those commands and arguments from?

To correctly configure a "normal" wifi connection use:

```
# ifconfig iwn0 nwid ID wpakey PASSPHRASE
```

Or for more than one network:

```
 # ifconfig iwn0 join ID wpakey PASSPHRASE
```

For more info, please refer to [ifconfig(8)](https://man.openbsd.org/ifconfig.8#IEEE_802.11_(WIRELESS_DEVICES)), [hostname.if(5)](https://man.openbsd.org/hostname.if.5) and [FAQ 6](https://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq6.html#Wireless).

Comment: Minor addition: `join` is meant to specify a network that will automatically be joined if found.  Its main use case is inside `/etc/hostname.*` files (`hostname.iwn0`, in the OP's case), where you can store a list of known networks (and their respective passphrases, if applicable).